# Why do I get double references when filtering a Vec?

Tags: rust

I am always having difficulties writing a proper iteration over `Vec`.
Perhaps this is because I don't understand yet properly when and why references are introduced.

For example

```
pub fn notInCheck(&self) -> bool { .... }       // tells whether king left in check
pub fn apply(&self, mv: Move) -> Self { ... }   // applies a move and returns the new position
pub fn rawMoves(&self, vec: &mut Vec<Move>) { ... } // generates possible moves, not taking chess into account

/// List of possible moves in a given position.
/// Verified to not leave the king of the moving player in check.
pub fn moves(&self) -> Vec<Move> {
    let mut vec: Vec<Move> = Vec::with_capacity(40);
    self.rawMoves(&mut vec);
    vec.iter().filter(|m| self.apply(**m).notInCheck()).map(|m| *m).collect()
}
```

where

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord, Hash)]
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct Move {
    mv: u32,
}
```

The iteration I wrote first was:

```
vec.iter().filter(|m| self.apply(m).notInCheck()).collect()
```

but, of course, the compiler gave all sorts of errors. In addressing these errors, I arrived finally at the version shown above, but while the compiler is happy, I'm not sure I am.

It looks like the vector doesn't hold Move's at all, but merely references to Moves? But then, where are the Move's stored? In addition, the `filter()` function adds another level of indirection. Is this correct? Please explain to me!

Bonus question: When I have vector elements with a type that implements `Copy`, is there a way to avoid all this useless reference taking stuff. I understand how it would make sense with vector elements of a notable size one does not want to copy around. However, I definitely want to avoid `&&value` in `filter()`. Can I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> It looks like the vector doesn't hold Move's at all, but merely references to Moves? But then, where are the Move's stored? In addition, the filter() function adds another level of indirection. Is this correct? Please explain to me!

No, `Vec<Move>` definitely holds moves. The part you're missing is that aside from `filter()` getting a reference to the iterator item, [`slice::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) creates an iterator on *references* to the slice (or vec here) items, so `Vec<Move>` -> `Iterator<Item=&Move>` -> `filter(predicate: FnMut(&&Move) -> bool)`, and that's why you've got two indirections in your `filter` callback.

> When I have vector elements with a type that implements Copy, is there a way to avoid all this useless reference taking stuff. I understand how it would make sense with vector elements of a notable size one does not want to copy around. However, I definitely want to avoid &&value in filter(). Can I?

Yes. You can use `into_iter` which will *consume* the source vector but iterate on the contained values directly, or you can use the [`Iterator::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) adapter which will `Copy` the iterator item, therefore going from `Iterator<Item=&T>` to `Iterator<Item=T>`. However `filter` will *never* get a `T`, the most it can get is an `&T` since otherwise the item would get "lost" (it would be consumed by the filter, which would only return a boolean, yielding… nothing useful).

The alternative is to use something like `filter_map` which does get a `T` input, and returns an `Option<U>`. Because (as the name indicates) it both filters and maps, it gets to consume the input item and either return an output item (possibly the same) or return "nothing" and essentially remove the item from the collection.

Incidentally, there's also an [`Iterator::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) adapter for types which are `Clone` but not (necessarily) `Copy`.

Also you could have basically done that by hand by just flipping `map` and `filter` around in the original:

```rust
    vec.iter().map(|m| *m).filter(|m| self.apply(*m).notInCheck()).collect()
```

`map` transforms the `Iterator<Item=&T>` into an `Iterator<Item=T>`, then `filter` just gets an `&T` instead of an `&&T`.

That aside, I don't really get why `apply` needs to *consume* the input move. Or why `rawMoves` doesn't just… create the vector internally and return it? I get the optimisation allowing for reusing the buffer but that seems like a case of premature optimisation maybe?

And your Move seems… both over-complicated and a bit too simple? If you just want to newtype a u32 then using a tuple-struct seems more than sufficient.

And `repr(transparent)` is wholly unnecessary, it's only a concern in FFI contexts where the newtype is intended as a type-safety measure which only exists on the Rust side (aka the newtype itself is *not* visible from / exposed to C, only the wrapped type is).

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comments. I begin to see a glimpse of light at the end of the tunnel. This is a chess engine written originally in Frege, a Haskell like language for the JVM, and I use it as a learning project to "translate" it into rust. Since performance and storage are both at a premium here, I thought it would be a good idea to stay with the read-only value semantics where possible. Thus, I prefer to pass a Move directly (I guess it's just a 32-bit word) and copying doesn't cost more than taking a reference.