# How to create a rust filter predicate for an iterator?

Tags: rust

```
pub struct S{
    a: u32
}
fn main() {
    let ve = vec![S{a: 1}, S{a: 2}];
    ve.iter().filter(filter_function);
}

fn filter_function(s: &S) -> bool {
    todo!()
}
```

Gives

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
   --> src/main.rs:6:22
    |
6   |     ve.iter().filter(filter_function);
    |               ------ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r &S) -> _`
    |               |
    |               required by a bound introduced by this call
...
9   | fn filter_function(s: &S) -> bool {
    | --------------------------------- found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r S) -> _`
    |
note: required by a bound in `filter`
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=caf542348c2b744abace8e7b6b30d766

And I have no idea why. The signatures are the same. What is wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get double references when filtering a Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303118/why-do-i-get-double-references-when-filtering-a-vec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signatures aren't quite the same. The expected type is a function which takes a `&'r &S`, while your function takes a `&'r S`. One has an extra layer of indirection.

You need a function that takes a double reference and calls `filter_function` with a single reference. We can do that with an explicit dereference.

```
ve.iter().filter(|x| filter_function(*x));
```

However, generally, Rust is pretty good at sorting out these kinds of dereferencing problems in lambdas, so we can simply write

```
ve.iter().filter(|x| filter_function(x));
```

and Rust is smart enough to handle the double reference for us.

It's worth mentioning that there should be no performance hit for the extra lambda. [`filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) takes a generic argument, which means it'll be statically dispatched and hence will be very easy for an optimizer to inline. So the performance should be equivalent to having a top-level function.

Comment: I don't like the implicit deref as it's very confusing. Of course this is subjective.

Comment: Understandable. I tend to prefer to let Rust handle things and try to minimize the amount of `&` and `*` I have to sprinkle throughout my code, but I can see why others would disagree.